# Show that $3^{4n+2} + 1$ is divisible by $10$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, modular-arithmetic, divisibility, exponentiation

I'm am a little bit stuck on this question, any help is appreciated.

Show that for every $n\in\mathbb{N}$, $3^{4n+2} + 1$ is divisible by $10$.

Comment: @DJC: Do you mean ends with $9$? $81$ is a multiple of $9$...

Comment: @Moron.  Oops!  I meant it is enough to show that $3^{4n+2} \equiv~9~mod~10$.

Comment: Use Euler's totient function. Eric has given almost the answer. Look at http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%27s_totient_function

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**Hint:** $$3^{4n+2}=3^{4n}\cdot 9$$ and $$3^{4n}\equiv 1 \pmod{10}$$ since $\phi(10)=4$.

Answer (score 9):

hint : $3^{4n+2} = (10-1)^{2n+1}$.

Answer (score 4):

What is the formation law of the remainders of the division by $10$ of the
powers $3^{n}$?

(For the notation see [modular arithmetic](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modular_arithmetic).)

$$\left\{ 
\begin{array}{c}
3\equiv 3\quad \pmod{10}  \\ 
3^{2}\equiv 9\quad \pmod{10}  \\ 
3^{3}\equiv 7\quad \pmod{10}  \\ 
3^{4}\equiv 1\quad \pmod{10} 
\end{array}\right. $$

$$\left\{ 
\begin{array}{c}
3^{5}\equiv 3\quad \pmod{10}  \\ 
3^{6}\equiv 9\quad \pmod{10}  \\ 
\cdots  \\ 
\cdots 
\end{array}\right. $$

So, with respect to the divisor $10$ the remainders of $3^{n}$ are periodic ($3,9,7,1,3,9,7,1,\dots$) with period $4$. This together with $4n+2\equiv 2\quad \pmod{4}$ yields $3^{4n+2}\equiv 3^{2}\quad \pmod{10}$. Also $1\equiv 1\quad \pmod{10}$. Hence, for all $n\ge 1$ $$3^{4n+2}+1\equiv 3^{2}+1\equiv 0\quad \pmod{10},$$

which means the remainders of the devision of $3^{4n+2}+1$ by $10$ are $0$.

Answer (score 1):

$$9+1=10$$
$$81 \times \left( 3^{4n-2} +1 \right) = 3^{4n+2} + 1 +80$$

Comment: Yes, induction works too.

Answer (score 1):

**HINT** $\rm\ \ \ A^K\: \equiv -1\ \ \Rightarrow\ \ A^{\:J+2\:K}\ \equiv\ A^{\:J}$

Answer (score 0):

$3^{4n+2} = 3^{2(2n+1)} = 9^{2n+1}$.  So your question is really asking about odd powers of 9 and then adding 1.  Let's look at powers of 9, and focus on the last digit (ie, take them mod 10):
$9^1 = 9,\ 9^2 = 1,\ 9^3=9^1\cdot 9^2=9 \cdot 1 = 9, \cdots$.  So the last digit in consecutive powers of 9 goes 9, 1, 9, 1, 9, 1, ...

Now consider adding 1 to only the odd terms above.

Answer (score 0):

$3^ {4*n} $ always gives a number ending in 1. Multiplying it by 9 gives a number ending in 9.

Adding 1 to it always gives a 0 at end.
Hence divisible by 10